# DOMException: Requested device not found GetUserMedia

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Trying to access IP Camera that is connected to a wifi.

I am connected to that wifi but I am getting error. If I try open using vlc I am able to connect but not getUserMedia has null.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent {
  @ViewChild('video') video: any; 
  constructor() {
  }
  hasGetUserMedia() {
  return !!(navigator.mediaDevices &&
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia);
}


ngAfterViewInit() {
  if (this.hasGetUserMedia()) {
    // Good to go!
    console.log("Gooddd................");
  } else {
    alert('getUserMedia() is not supported by your browser');
  }
  let _video = this.video.nativeElement;
  if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
      .then(function (stream) {
        _video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        _video.play();
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
  }
}

<video #video width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
```

Comment: getUserMedia is not meant to connect to ip-cams, but to webcams, i.e the ones that are plugged directly to your computer (the one that runs your web-browser). For your ip-cam, simply set its feed's url (if any) as the src of a video element. And if you ever want to use webcams in one of your projects, note that URL.createObjectURL(MediaStream)  is deprecated, you should set the video's srcObject to this MediaStream directly instead.

Answer (score 11):

This happens when you dont have any device to capture video or capture audio

try checking if your webcam and your microphone are working fine

Answer (score 5):

Try without "audio: true". Its help for my. (Microphone are not work).
And check webcam on other sites.
Maybe need check permissions for this page.

Answer (score 1):

try changing this line:

```
_video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
```

with this one:

```
_video.srcObject = stream;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this line to initialize the webcam and microphone:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have connected external camera through USB i was able to get the devices, i was getting kind of devices as audiooutput and videoinput, and there was no audioinput(microphone device) but while i was requesting for devices i passed constraints as..

```
function Webcam(){
  this.constraints = {
    video: true,
    audio: true
  }
  this.userMedia = null;
  this.mediaDevices = navigator.mediaDevices;
  this.initialize = function(){
    this.userMedia = this.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(this.constraints);
  }
}

let webcam = new Webcam();
    webcam.initialize();
```

So Promise not satisified and getting error as Requested device not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching an earpiece or earplug with microphone to your PC. mine has no microphone that was why I got that error

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31096970)

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also occur on some mobile devices (Sony XA2 running Android) if you had previously already created a [`MediaStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream).

The solution that I found was to make sure to stop all the tracks of previous streams that you created.

```
 this.stream.getTracks().forEach(t => {
    t.stop();
    // I don't think removeTrack is necessary, but just keeping it.
    this.stream.removeTrack(t);
 });
```

Without the previous code you can't seem to toggle camera on certain Android devices: [(Demo)](https://jsfiddle.net/3pbgm9ua/33/show),
[(Code)](https://jsfiddle.net/3pbgm9ua/33/)
The error shown was `DOMException: Requested device not found`

By stopping previous tracks: you are able to start a new stream:
[(Demo)](https://jsfiddle.net/3pbgm9ua/35/show)
[Code](https://jsfiddle.net/3pbgm9ua/35/)

Note: I also answered a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73550841/1123985

Answer (score 0):

I have mic and camera but I was getting the same error. I was pretty sure that was related to laptop setting, because I tried everything. turns out my laptop was blocking access to the media. I am using linux and laptop brand name is MSI, I started to look for any sign that related to the camera setting. On F6 button, my laptop has a webcam icon. So I clicked on

```
fn + F6
```

It works now. most likely sometimes I click on fn+* keys to see any difference and I blocked the camera access.