# JS VIDEO | DOMException: Could not start video source

Tags: javascript

I want to get a video from the webcam using JS but no footage.

***MESSAGE:***

> DOMException: Could not start video source

***App.js***

```
const video = document.getElementById("video");

function startVideo() {
  navigator.getUserMedia(
    {
      video: {}
    },
    stream => (video.srcObject = stream),
    err => console.log(err)
  );
}

startVideo();
```

***index.html***

```
...
<body>
    <video id="video" width="720" height="540" autoplay muted></video>
</body>
...
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Is your browser asking about permissions to access the camera? Which browser are you using?

Comment: @DawidPura Yes wants permission. i using Chrome but Firefox, Opera same problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TLDR: I have tested your code and had to change it a bit:

https://codepen.io/puradawid/pen/PoqxzPQ

It looks like the problem lays here:

```
navigator.getUserMedia({
    video: {}
  },
  stream => { video.srcObject = stream },
  err => console.log(err)
);
```

Regarding to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) `navigator.getUserMedia` is deprecated and there is `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` that supports it. However, changing that up doesn't solve the correct problem which is your callback functions. This method returns `Promise` that is controlled by `.then()`, so changing it allows me to see my face in codepen:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true
}).then(
  stream => (video.srcObject = stream),
  err => console.log(err)
);
```

Comment: I get the same error ("Could not start video source") intermittently, but I am using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(..)... but sometimes it works - and sometimes it doesn't. Repeatedly retrying the getUserMedia seems to eventually gain access - but I'm still searching for a final solution

Comment: Have anyone found a solution for this? For me, this is happening only on Android 11 devices... Cant figure it out why

Comment: @leodavinci1 same issue, same android 11. Do u have any solution

Comment: @sundar did you make sure to clean up previous streams that you created? Stopping all the tracks for old streams fixed my issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73550841/1123985

Comment: @user1432181 We too have one app which is built on an electron module. We get the same error when trying to access the camera but if we retry again then the stream is getting. But problem is to get the stream it is taking 22seconds. This happens only in Mac builds and that too in M1 & M2 processor chips. Please let us know if you have solved it.

Comment: @Dawid-Pura please please once look at my code too, really need someones else point of you, thanks- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76396072/react-camera-sometimes-not-loading-after-user-allows-camera-permission-code

Answer (score 38):

If anyone else is having this problem and nothing else helps. Make sure that your camera is not already claimed/used by a different software/browser.

Comment: 25 upvotes but no comments or explanations? What exactly does this mean, and is there a way I can check this?

Comment: this should only affect Windows machines. other OSs gracefully handle multiple applications using the same camera device

Comment: Thank you for this response, I had a bad time with my code before reading this, why would this problem be just in windows it really sucks, and as the comment above mention it would be great if there's some sort of explanation

Comment: On LINUX: 
you can check if other devices use your webcam if you execute: 

`lsof | grep --ignore-case /dev/vid`

Comment: @Gisheri I'm testing Quagga2 Bar code reader with multiple browsers and this was indeed the reason why my firefox failed to open camera

Comment: Just confirming that I am getting this error on macOS, so I'd probably say it's not just bound to windows

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem on certain android devices (Sony XA2) when trying to toggle the camera on a mobile browser because I am calling `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` repeatedly on each camera toggle.

The solution that I found was to make sure to stop all the tracks in previous streams that you created.

```
 this.stream.getTracks().forEach(t => {
    t.stop();
    this.stream.removeTrack(t);
 });
```

Without the previous code you can't seem to toggle camera on certain Android devices: [(Demo)](https://jsfiddle.net/3pbgm9ua/33/show),
[(Code)](https://jsfiddle.net/3pbgm9ua/33/)
The error shown was `DOMException: Requested device not found`

By stopping previous tracks: you are able to start a new stream:
[(Demo)](https://jsfiddle.net/3pbgm9ua/35/show)
[Code](https://jsfiddle.net/3pbgm9ua/35/)

Note: The following code snippet doesn't seem to execute in stack overflow due to security restrictions, so please use the jsfiddle links.

```js
class Camera {
  constructor({ video }) {
    this.facingMode = "environment";
    this.video = video;
    video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
      video.play();
    };
  }
  async toggleCamera() {
    if (this.facingMode === "environment") {
      this.facingMode = "user";
    } else {
      this.facingMode = "environment";
    }
    try {
        if (this.stream){
            /* On some android devices, it is necessary to stop the previous track*/
        this.stream.getTracks().forEach(t => t.stop());
      }
      this.stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: {
          facingMode:  this.facingMode,
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    this.video.srcObject = this.stream;
  }
}

const camera = new Camera({
     video: document.querySelector("video"),
});
const button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    camera.toggleCamera();
});
```

```html
<button>
  Toggle Camera
</button>
<video></video>
```

Comment: I still get an error using the fiddle with firefox android...
when I manually give permission for the camera all is well but when i check the checkbox for remembering my decision it throws the `DOMException: Starting videoinput failed`
any ideas how to fix that issue or is it a bug in firefox?

Comment: It looks like this is bug reported in firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1663913

Comment: that one closed, i opened this one instead since its only on specific devices:  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1863542

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10 go to settings->privacy->App permission(left side)->Microphone-> enable 'Allow apps to access your microphone'
After that retry with your JS program....It will work!![image: Error solved!! DOM Exception Could not start video source]

Comment: If the above post didn't worked; go to the browser settings and change the camera & microphone settings ie check if you using the correct camera and mic, that was an issue in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all the other solution but nothing is work. Then finally i need to uninstall my camera driver in `Device Manager` and then scan for hardware changes. Try to run the app again and it's working.

I'm building electron desktop app in windows 10.
`electron: 15.3.0`

Source video that helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XE2ULFlzkxw

Answer (score 1):

For someone getting this same error here, my issue was related with the constraints... I was using:

```
video: {
  width: {
    ideal: 1080
  }
}
```

and changed to:

```
video: {
  width: {
    max: 1080
  }
}
```

and everything worked!

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue for android devices.

Answer (score 0):

Also look into Feature-Policy HTTP header, both on the website and on the host web server config, and make sure camera access is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone have such an error and you are working on a laptop. You can try bending your laptop monitor in both directions. Sometimes the cable comes loose. This helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the browser settings for camera and noticed that the default camera was showing as "Leap Motion" which is not a standard camera device. I changed to an actual webcam and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this type of error also appears when you try to make a peer-to-peer call system and your tests are done on the same device. The camera is already used by the initiator and the receiver can no longer activate the camera.