# Could not start audio source error on mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, electron, chromium

I am trying to make a screen recorder with `electron.js`

I have used `desktopCapturer.getSources` to get all the screens which is working fine but when I am tring to get stream using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` it throws a error :

```
> DOMException: Error could not start audio source
```

```js
const handleRecordActions = async () => {
    const { id } = activeScreen;
    try {
      // console.log("here", navigator);
      stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: {
          mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
            chromeMediaSourceId: id,
          },
        },
        video: {
          mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
            chromeMediaSourceId: id,
          },
        },
      });
      stream.stop = function () {
        stream.getAudioTracks().forEach(function (track) {
          track.stop();
        });
        stream.getVideoTracks().forEach(function (track) {
          //in case... :)
          track.stop();
        });
      };
      setStream(stream);
      handleStream(stream);

      // console.log({ stream, d: stream.getAudioTracks() });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

If I make `audio: false` then it throws different error :

```
> DOMException: Error starting screen capture
```

I am working on :

```
Ubuntu : 20.04
Electron : ^16.0.4
```

#### Edit :

I have confirmed that this error is occurring in linux (Ubuntu) only as the same code is working seamlessly in windows.

Comment: How have you implemented `setStream` and `handleStream` methods? Check if it's [permission issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60837628/15273968).

Comment: No the code never reaches `handleStream` and `setStream`. It throws error from `stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`

Comment: What kind of permission settings do you have in your browser? Do you reject all (like camera, screen sharing service etc)? If yes, you will never get any stream from that browser

Comment: Its not a browser its a desktop app created on electron.

Comment: @akds This is how Electron handles web API permissions: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#5-handle-session-permission-requests-from-remote-content

Comment: @ShubhamKumar Can you use the mic and camera in web apps in your browser in Ubuntu? It might be a permission issue with OS-level permissions rather than Electron itself.

Comment: Yes I can use mic and even camera