# Unable to run testcafe tests on CI/CD gitlab but works fine locally on the runner

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, testcafe

I am seeing an issue running testcafe tests on the gitlab runner. The tests runs fine locally on the gitlab runner, but when run off the CI/CD pipeline it fails. Below is my .yaml code -

```
test-e2e-windows:
  stage: test
  cache:
    <<: *global_cache
    policy: pull
  #needs: ['yarn-install']
  tags:
    - win32
  script:
    - yarn install
    - yarn run test:e2e
```

Below is the error I see -

$ yarn run test:e2e
Running tests in:

- Chrome 99.0.4844.82 / Windows 10
  Audio Configuration Combination
  × Inbuilt_Mic_Recording_1Ch_48 khz_16 bit_64 kbps_opus_webm

  1. A JavaScript error occurred on
     "https://dolby-web-sdk-dev.net/sandbox/index.html".
     Repeat test actions in the browser and check the console for errors.
     To ignore client-side JavaScript errors, enable the
     "--skip-js-errors" CLI option, or set the "skipJsErrors"
     configuration file property to "true".
     If the website only throws this error when you test it with
     TestCafe, please create a new issue at:
     "https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md".
     JavaScript error details:
     NotFoundError: Requested device not found
     No stack trace available

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

According to the "Requested device not found" error message, this issue is related to your application implementation:

- [DOMException: Requested device not found GetUserMedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52479734/domexception-requested-device-not-found-getusermedia).
- [Requested device not found - Unable to access Camera and Microphone](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js/issues/86)

I can assume that it tries to access some device on a virtual machine but fails due to the fact that this device does not exist. In my opinion, the best way to resolve this issue is to manually handle this error in your application.
If my assumptions are wrong, please create a new GitHub issue using this [template](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) and share a minimal working example illustrating the issue.

Comment: A physical system is setup as a gitlab runner and not an virtual machine. I have added --skip-js-errors argument and seems to get past this, but could not locate to find the element. I tried the following to figure out what is happening, but seems both had problems -        1. Try taking screenshot . Currently there is an open bug  https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6886#issuecomment-1120794421 that prevents taking screenshot in headless mode. 2. Run in UI mode, but I cant seem to see the UI when running from gitlab CI/CD pipeline. I am running around circles.

Comment: We've made a lot of changes to our codebase since issue [6886](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6886#issuecomment-1120794421) was discovered. Apparently, it should not be reproduced in the latest version of TestCafe. Could you please update TestCafe to the latest version and try to take a screenshot in headless mode again?